# Tame Moduli Space of a stack without finite inertia

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an Artin stack over $S$.

In the paper by Jarod Alper, *Good moduli spaces for Artin stacks*, [Ann. Inst. Fourier **63** (2013) 2349-2402](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_2013__63_6_2349_0), a tame moduli space is defined as a morphism $\phi:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow X$ such that

1. $\phi$ is a good moduli space.
2. For all geometric points $Spec(k)\rightarrow S$, the map $$[\mathcal{X}(k)]\rightarrow X(k)$$ is a bijection of sets.

Are there known examples of Artin stacks without finite inertia which admit tame moduli spaces?

Comment: I have not studied Alper's notion, but it seems to me like the stack $B \mathbb{G}_m$ satisfies all of the properties.